# I am using macros button in excel that runs a python script. and the path directory of that python script is D drive but instead it giving me C drive?

Tags: python, excel

I am using excel macro button in my excel file. on clicking that button one python script get called and that script is in D drive. and in that script I am doing os.getcwd().It should give me D drive but instead its giving me C drive.

I am expecting that it should give me D drive path for os.getcwd as it present in D drive but giving me c drive

Comment: Can you share the excel macro you run the python script with?

Comment: Sub RunPythonScript()
Dim shell As Object
Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim pythonExePath As String
pythonExePath = """C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"""
Dim pythonScriptPath As String
pythonScriptPath = "D:\xxx\main.py"
Dim cmd As String
cmd = "cmd.exe /c " & pythonExePath & " " & pythonScriptPath & " & pause"
shell.Run cmd, 1, True
End Sub

Comment: The working directory for the [shell is determined by `shell.CurrentDirectory`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-change-the-working-folder-of-a-script/), not sure what the default is. Depending on what you actually wanna do, parsing directories might be easier in VBA or python.